# How to get the contents and versions of ListItem

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am very new to shareopoint development. In my project I want to read the contents of the ListItems according to its versions. Here is my pseudo code

```
                      foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
                            {
                                var item=  wb.GetItemById(oListItem.Id);

                                clientcontext.Load(item, 
                                it => it.Id, it => it.DisplayName,   
                                it=>it.ContentType,it=>it.File);

                                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                                Console.WriteLine(itm.DisplayName);                                    

                                var strm = item.File.ListItemAllFields;

                                clientcontext.Load(strm);
                                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery(); 
                            }
```

How can I read the contents of ListItem according to its version?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code.

```
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion itemVersion in pageItem.File.Versions)
{
      pageVersion = itemVersion.VersionLabel + ";" + pageVersion;
      Console.WriteLine(itemVersion.VersionLabel);
}
```

Hope this helps to give you some idea to start with.

---

**To get the older version content**

You have to checkout the file.
Make previous version as current version.
Get the content of the file
Undo checkout.

Comment: Thanks this gives me the version of the item. But how can I get contents of the item

Comment: Edited my answer.!!